# How to make maven fail is 'jar' packaing is not a jar?

Tags: maven, maven-3

My environment runs behind a proxy. 
If the proxy is not defined, you will get an HTML file with an error.

In these cases maven still downloads the artifacts marked as 'jar' , but the content is HTML, and so it fails with message `error in opening zip file`

And so I find myself compiling, failing, deleting invalid jars manually and so on.

I would like to prevent maven from downloading invalid jars. 
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Than your configuration for your proxy (settings.xml) is wrong? Best would be to [activate checking of checksums](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) ....

Comment: It also sounds like your proxy is bad. If the proxy has issues it should be sending the right status code (ie in the 400s or 500s). Instead it must be sending back a 200.